# Get object's class and its constructor, Reflection in Android

Tags: java, android, class, object, reflection

suppose i have classA and classB(generic), reference http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.lang.reflect/Constructors.html

I am passing a customobject from classA to classB, now i am wanting constructor of customobject in classB and call it

classA

```
customclass objCustomclass;

classB mClassB;

mClassB.getConstructorAndCall(objCustomclass);
```

classB

```
public void getConstructorAndCall(Object objCustomclass);

try {
    Object filledObject = objCustomclass.getClass().newInstance();
        // here i need to call  filledObject's contructor
} catch (Exception e) { }
```

I am able to create object as the instance of custom object but what about constructor.

note: `getConstructorAndCall()` is a commom method and in that object is of unknown type that means any class can pass its object.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

well if the constructor is empty, then I think that what you have should run the constructor.  Anything more complicated, like, passing parameters to the function can be done through:

```
Constructor[] constructors = objCustomClass.getClass().getConstructors()
for (int i = 0; i < constructors.length; i++) {
  Constructor c = constructors[i];
  Class[] paramTypes = c.getParameterTypes();
  Object[] params;
  // do fancy stuff here - it helps if you know what the constructors take beforehand
  Object filledObject = c.newInstance(params);
}
```

[Constructor with parameters](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html#newInstance(java.lang.Object...))

Comment: But calling with parameters doesn't apply to constructors. That's why I talked about the solution design. I guess he might need prototyping his objects or something similar, instead of relying solely on the constructor.

Comment: @VicentePlata Agreed, but before any conclusion lemme search workaround

Comment: @VicentePlata how do you mean parameters don't apply to constructors? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html#newInstance(java.lang.Object[])

Comment: Since edit is no longer possible, it should be noted that it is `length` not `getLength()` and this is helpful when you need a constructor, but the class only includes a specialized one with no "default" available.

Answer (score 0):

From the JavaDoc for java.lang.Class ( http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance() ):

> Creates a new instance of the class represented by this Class object.
>   The class is instantiated as if by a **new** expression with an **empty**
>    **argument list**. The class is initialized if it has not already been
>   initialized.

I. E. the newInstance() method always uses the default constructor.

Most times I see people using new instance and requiring a particular constructor or signature, it happens to be due to a lack on the solution design. You might want to double check if a pattern applies to the solution you need.

Comment: Kinda. I mean, instead of requiring a particular constructor, it'd be easier to make sure that a particular method (init or something) is always called. You can achieve this through a factory, for example.

Comment: Fortunately if it's not the constructor, but init, then you can call it with parameters via reflection.